# Read error while indexing .vscode/settings.json: Permission denied

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, permission-denied

When I run `git add .`, I get the following error:

```
jskids ❯❯❯ git add .
error: read error while indexing .vscode/settings.json: Permission denied
error: .vscode/settings.json: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file '.vscode/settings.json'
fatal: adding files failed
```

Is there any workaround?

Let me explain the details.
I created a Javascript program, called `jskids`, with VS Code.
Now I want to connect it to my own GitHub, so I ran `git init` under `jskids` directory.

Now the directory looks like this:

```
jskids ❯❯❯ la -1
.
..
.git
.gitignore
.vscode
index.html
program.js
```

I also installed `gitignore` to VS Code in order to ignore the `.vscode` directory.

The content of `.gitignore` is:

```
vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
!.vscode/*.code-snippets

# Local History for Visual Studio Code
.history/

# Built Visual Studio Code Extensions
*.vsix
```

... Nevertheless, I still get the same error.

I even closed the `jskids` on VS Code and VS Code itself, and opened `Git Bash` and ran `git add .` ... it still gives me **a similar error** (**Edited**):

```
jskids (master)
$ git add .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: read error while indexing .vscode/settings.json: Bad file descriptor
error: .vscode/settings.json: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file '.vscode/settings.json'
fatal: adding files failed
```

**Added `ls -la` ran on VS Code, per the request from @AD7six**:

```
jskids ❯❯❯ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 user-name user-name   4096 Mar 21 00:34 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 user-name user-name   4096 Mar 20 22:00 ..        
drwxrwxrwx 1 user-name user-name   4096 Mar 21 00:35 .git      
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user-name user-name    220 Mar 20 22:55 .gitignore
drwxrwxrwx 1 user-name user-name   4096 Dec 18 22:53 .vscode   
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user-name user-name   1713 Dec 19 22:41 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user-name user-name  16535 Dec 19 23:29 program.js
(NOTE: I removed some unrelated filenames.)
```

**Added `head .vscode/settings.json`**

```
jskids ❯❯❯ head .vscode/settings.json
head: error reading '.vscode/settings.json': Permission denied
```

**Added `ls -la .vscode/settings.json`**

```
jskids ❯❯❯ ls -la .vscode/settings.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user-name user-name 37 Dec 18 22:53 .vscode/settings.json
```

**Added `touch new.txt` on VS Code

```
jskids ❯❯❯ touch new.txt
jskids ❯❯❯ ls -la new.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user-name user-name      0 Mar 21 02:10 new.txt
```

I've tried all what I can think of.
What am I missing?
Is my `gitignore` working?
(Obviously, `.vscode` directory is NOT ignored at all.)

My environment is Windows 10, VS Code, WSL (Ubuntu), Git Bash.

Comment: This could be a file system glitch. Honestly, it's weird and unusual. Can you try creating a new directory structure with copies of the files, and see if the problem occurs again there?

Comment: @joanis Sorry, could you wait for a sec? Now you're looking at is the result of my `Git Bash`. Let me paste the result of `VS Code`, instead.

Comment: Thanks - what those edits show is that it's not a trivial ownership/permissions issue. Since you are not able to read the file, it's also not a git problem. I suggest to edit the question  (and retag) to focus on what's known i.e. 'cannot read files in ubuntu-wsl created on windows'. That's not something I'm familiar with - good luck :).

Comment: @AD7six The owner of `.vscode/settings.json` is also me. However, the names are different. On `VS Code`: `user-name1` <=> On `Git Bash`: `user-name2`. Both names are mine, though.

Comment: I get the feeling you're obfuscating significant details... If you `touch some-file` is that owned by `user-name` or a different user? Irrespective, based on what's in the question I cannot help here :).

Comment: I tried `(sudo) chmod 777 .vscode/settings.json` both on `VS Code` and `Git Bash`, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @AD7six `touch new.txt` on VS Code created a new file owned by me (user-name1). I did the same on `Git Bash` and it also created a new file owned by me (user-name2). I can freely read and write these files in both ways (VS Code <=> Git Bash); `echo Hello > new.txt` etc.

Comment: @joanis Sorry for this late reply. I created a new directory with the copies of the files and the problem is gone (`git add .` works fine without any error). So, should we always create a new directory and then run `git init` and `git add .`? I still don't know the root cause, but should I close this question ...?

Comment: I'm moving forward. Thank you guys, @joanis and @AD7six!

Comment: @IanHacker I don't think you always need to do this, no. Most of the time, you won't. I really think it's some weird file system glitch that occurred and probably won't be reproducible. Yes, closing the question is the right thing to do, since it won't be reproducible.

Comment: @joanis OK, let me close this question because it won't be reproducible. I really thank you guys for your efforts.